# How to execute U-SQL job with code behind from .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, azure-data-lake, u-sql, data-lake

I have a U-SQL job that uses custom Extractors in code behind. And I need to run it on demand from the C# code.

I found a way to submit job by passing the script like a string. Can I execute somehow the script with a custom extractor?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an assembly with code behind and upload it to data lake analytics.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2016/08/26/how-to-register-u-sql-assemblies-in-your-u-sql-catalog/

https://dev.to/alanmbarr/azure-data-lake-custom-extractor-2hbg

Then you can add a reference to the assembly and use the custom extractors on your code.